# IndexError: list index out of range when in python, even when the range exists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am sure that the range which I am trying to access exists, but still, the program shows error. I am trying to make a program which will sum up the values in a column corresponding to the values in the other column.

for example:

```
   28400    4
   28400    34 
   28400    9
   65478    2
   65478    5
   65478    3
```

what my program will do is, it will add up 4,34 and 9 and then it will add up 2,5 and 3 and then following will be the output-

```
   47
   47
   47
   10
   10
   10
```

I am importing data from a CSV file. following is the code-

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    assessment = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset original/studentVle2.csv')


    assessment = assessment.values

    count=0
    stucount=28400
    sumc=[]
    i=0
    for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
        if(stucount==stu):
            count = count + assessment[i,5]
            i=i+1
        else:
            sumc.append(count)
            count = 0
            count = count + assessment[i,5]
            i=i+1
        stucount=stu

    #print(sumc)

    stucount=28400
    i=0
    a=[]
    for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
        if(stucount==stu):
            a.append(sumc[i])
            stucount = stu
        else:
            i=i+1
            a.append(sumc[i])
            stucount = stu

    print(a)
```

Error:

```
        File "/home/user/Documents/final project files/test.py", line 36, in <module>
        a.append(sumc[i])
        IndexError: list index out of range
```

and by the way, before adding some lines, like i=i+1,stucount=stu this error was not shown, but now it shows even though what happening is the same.

Comment: Place i=i+1  below stucount = stu and then try

Comment: that is the thing , I want to increment i before a.append(sumc[i]) inside else

Comment: Yes...thats it.

Comment: Did it work bruh

Comment: yes it did but the output is different then what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are not adding assessment value to `sumc` list for the last student after the loop ends. So, for `n` unique student id, the list length is only `n-1`. After `for` loop, add `sumc.append(count)`. See below.

```
assessment = assessment.values

count=0
stucount=28400
sumc=[]
i=0
for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
    if(stucount==stu):
        count = count + assessment[i,5]
        i=i+1
    else:
        sumc.append(count)
        count = 0
        count = count + assessment[i,5]
        i=i+1
    stucount=stu

sumc.append(count)
print(sumc)

stucount=28400
i=0
a=[]
for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
    if(stucount==stu):
        a.append(sumc[i])
        stucount = stu
    else:
        a.append(sumc[i])
        stucount = stu
        i=i+1

print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Place `i=i+1` below `stucount = stu` and then try

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

assessment = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset original/studentVle2.csv')


assessment = assessment.values

count=0
stucount=28400
sumc=[]
i=0
for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
    if(stucount==stu):
        count = count + assessment[i,5]
        i=i+1
    else:
        sumc.append(count)
        count = 0
        count = count + assessment[i,5]
        i=i+1
    stucount=stu

#print(sumc)

stucount=28400
i=0
a=[]
for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
    if(stucount==stu):
        a.append(sumc[i])
        stucount = stu
    else:
        a.append(sumc[i])
        stucount = stu
        i=i+1

print(a)
```

The output will be different and change accordingly....error will be removed

Comment: Does this code not skip adding sum of assessment score to `sumc` for last student id?

Answer (score 3):

Here, i'm just going by your initial problem statement of what you have and what you want to get.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[28400,4],
                   [28400,34],
                   [28400,9],
                   [65478,2],
                   [65478,5],
                   [65478,3]], columns=list('AB'))
sums = df.groupby('A').B.sum()
df.A.map(sums)
```

And you get

```
0    47
1    47
2    47
3    10
4    10
5    10
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes this can work. but I don't understand what is happening there in my code. why is it showing out of range when it is in range

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add `i=i+1` after the error line `a.append(sumc[i])`.
Because in your code, may out of range of list at last.

Comment: I want to increment i before a.append(sumc[i]) or else my output will be wrong, look at the example I have given

Comment: you could init `i` from `-1` ,    
```
    i=-1
    a=[]
    for stu in assessment[:,2:3]:
        if(stucount==stu):
            i=i+1
            a.append(sumc[i])
            stucount = stu
        else:
            i=i+1
            a.append(sumc[i])
            stucount = stu

    print(a)
```